# SQL problem with data conversions and divide by zero (pulling my hair out)

Tags: sql

I have been googling my butt off but I can't solve this. So I reach for those more experienced than myself.  Thank you and please!

I have a table with a few important columns:

- AvailableQty which is varchar(200)
- hardAllocQty which is varchar(200)
- Value which is numberic(19,4)

I am trying to add the quantities in the two qty columns and then divide by the value.  But I'm getting "Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric." and sometimes other errors depending on how I try to troubleshoot it such as "Divide by zero error encountered".  Here is the code.  Any help on how to make this work would be great. I think the issue is somewhere in the first half of the isnull()

```
    select distinct part.Part_Num, part.[Part Description], part.[Part Type],

isnull(
(select (sum(cast(stock.AvailableQty as bigint))+sum(cast(stock.HardAllocQty as bigint)))/
sum(cast(stock.Value as bigint)) from dbo.StockAvailability Stock 
WHERE stock.PartNo = part.Part_Num),

(SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN Avg(cast(NULLIF(po.cost,0) as BIGINT)) IS NULL THEN format(Avg(po.cost),'c')
    ELSE format(Avg(cast(NULLIF(po.cost,0) as BIGINT)),'c')
END 
from dbo.tblPO_DETAIL_DATA PO WHERE PO.[Part Number] = part.Part_Num AND
cast(po.[PO Date] as date) > DATEADD(MONTH,@LookBack60,GETDATE()))
) 
as 'Avg Cost'

from dbo.UNIQUE_PARTS_LIST part
```

Comment: Can you include sample data? What DBMS are you using (e.g. SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL)?

Comment: Use ISNULL+ NULLIF. Remember that any number divided by 0 will cause exception, you will have to find a workaround for this scenario

Comment: In MS SQL Server, you would use the ISNUMERIC() function before trying to cast. But why are your quantities in a non-numeric column in the first place? This will seriously slow things down. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Please include the schema for `tblPO_DETAIL_DATA` and `StockAvailability`

Comment: What is the type of `po.cost` for instance?

Comment: Step 1 if you really want to solve this is use correct data types - your quantities should not be varchar

Answer (score 0):

### tldr;

On first inspection, this CASE statement looks offending:

```
CASE 
    WHEN Avg(cast(NULLIF(po.cost,0) as BIGINT)) IS NULL 
        THEN format(Avg(po.cost),'c')
        ELSE format(Avg(cast(NULLIF(po.cost,0) as BIGINT)),'c')
END
```

I can't justify it and suspect it is a cut'n'paste issue or it's just half formed. When there are zeros, you want to average across all rows, and when there are no zeros you still want to average across all rows without conversion... otherwise you do want to use conversion.

> Do you want the 0s for `po.cost` to be included in the *average cost* or do you want to exclude them?

I suspect it is the `format(Avg(po.cost),'c')` that is causing the problems, mainly because every other reference to `po.cost` uses a *cast* and this does not.

Quick fix if you want to exclude the 0s from the `Avg Cost` (and `po.cost` _already **IS** numeric)

```
(SELECT FORMAT(AVG(NULLIF(po.cost,0)),'c')
 FROM dbo.tblPO_DETAIL_DATA PO 
 WHERE PO.[Part Number] = part.Part_Num 
   AND cast(po.[PO Date] as date) > DATEADD(MONTH,@LookBack60,GETDATE()))
) 
as 'Avg Cost'
```

If `po.Cost` is **NOT** numeric, then use this instead:

```
(SELECT FORMAT(AVG(
    CASE
        WHEN ISNUMERIC(po.cost)
            THEN CAST(po.cost AS BIGINT)
            ELSE 0
    END 
    ),'c')
 FROM dbo.tblPO_DETAIL_DATA PO 
 WHERE PO.[Part Number] = part.Part_Num 
   AND cast(po.[PO Date] as date) > DATEADD(MONTH,@LookBack60,GETDATE()))
) 
as 'Avg Cost'
```

### But lets explore this in detail...

Before adding aggregates into the mix, take a step back and make sure your source data is correct, run the following queries to validate your conversions:

```
select cast(stock.AvailableQty as bigint)
     , cast(stock.HardAllocQty as bigint)
     , cast(stock.Value as bigint)
from dbo.StockAvailability Stock

select cast(po.cost as bigint)
     , cast(po.[PO Date] as date)
from dbo.tblPO_DETAIL_DATA po
```

If the data from those two queries is OK, then shouldn't be an issue, if it is an issue, you can try to isolate the rows that have invalid values, the first option I would try is to use the [IsNumeric()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) check, you can do this in two ways, 1 - just exclude non-numerics, or 2, query for the non-numerics, so you can inspect the results and then come up with a better solution. So run the following to identify the issues:

```
select stock.AvailableQty, stock.HardAllocQty, stock.Value
from dbo.StockAvailability Stock
WHERE ISNUMERIC(stock.AvailableQty) = 0 OR ISNUMERIC(stock.HardAllocQty) = 0 OR ISNUMERIC(stock.Value) = 0

-- Finding the number of invalid values might help drive the solution?
select po.cost, COUNT(*)
from dbo.tblPO_DETAIL_DATA po
WHERE ISNUMERIC(po.cost)
GROUP BY po.cost
```

If the invalid value should be counted as a zero, then we can use `CASE` logic to resolve the value, or if there is a specific value that should be treated as `NULL` you can use `NULLIF()`, or if the specific value should be 0 you can use `ISNULL(NULLIF())`

> Why zero vs null matters - zeros wont affect `SUM()` aggregates, but they will be counted in the record count when computing `AVG()`

If your recordset commonly has `'NaN'` as a stored value instead of null, in `columnA` and you want the whole record to be excluded from recordset then an easy option is to add that in the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE columnA <> 'N/A'
```

However if you want the rest of the record, but just need this value interpreted as a `NULL` so that it will be *excluded* from the aggregate calculations you can use `NULLIF()`:
*My personal preference is to alias the column with the same name if an alias is required, the user or next operation doesn't need access to the original value after we have sanitized it like this*

```
SELECT NULLIF(columnA, 'N/A') AS columnA
```

Again, if you know a *specific* value that you want to treat as a zero in aggregates, we can use `ISNULL(NULLIF)`:

```
SELECT ISNULL(NULLIF(columnA, 'N/A'),0) AS columnA
```

If you have many different values, you can use nested `NULLIF()` and then `COALESCE()`, but it quickly gets unmanageable:

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(columnA, 'N/A'), NULLIF(columnA, '-'), 0) AS columnA
```

You can get more control over this type of logic or short-circuit it with a call to `ISNUMERIC()` in a `CASE` statement:

```
-- output as null if non-numeric
SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(columnA) = 1 THEN columnA END AS columnA
...
-- ouput as 0 is non-numeric
SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(columnA) = 1 THEN columnA ELSE 0 END AS columnA
```

---

Once you have identified the offending columns and decided if they should be excluded or treated as zeros, then you could re-write your inline sub-queries into a more set-based operation, this process and the reasoning is explained in this article [How to Use GROUP BY with Distinct Aggregates and Derived tables](https://www.sqlteam.com/articles/how-to-use-group-by-with-distinct-aggregates-and-derived-tables) and applies if there are many parts in the source list.

> Having a `DISTINCT` in a result-set that is returning aggregates is a red flag that points to inefficiencies or flaws in the aggregation logic, a distinct is often put in as a *quick fix* on a query, when aggregates are concerned better scoping or a `GROUP BY` is often more efficient.

In MS SQL Server, `CROSS APPLY` is a useful mechanism for evaluating conversions and other functions, it gives us a clean way to separate the steps involved in formatting your data or evaluating repetitive logic once and reusing the result, instead of re-evaluating the same expression many times in a query.

> That is the main point to structuring your query using `CROSS APPLY` by defining the expression once, when you need to alter the logic you wont accidentally leave some expressions in their original (and not potentially invalid) state.

*CTEs are used here to separate the concerns, you could write them as inline sub query based joins, but IMO it gets harder to read and interpret the query*

```
;
WITH StockByPart as (
(
    SELECT Stock.PartNo
         , SUM(numerics.AvailableQty)+SUM(numerics.HardAllocQty))/SUM(numerics.Value) AS AvgPrice
    FROM dbo.StockAvailability Stock 
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT   
          CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(stock.AvailableQty) = 1 THEN CAST(stock.AvailableQty as bigint) END AS AvailableQty
        , CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(stock.HardAllocQty) = 1 THEN CAST(stock.HardAllocQty as bigint) END AS HardAllocQty
        , CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(stock.Value) = 1 THEN CAST(stock.Value as bigint) END AS [Value]
    ) Numerics
    GROUP BY Stock.PartNo
)
, POByPart as (
    SELECT PO.[Part Number]
         , SUM(numerics.AvailableQty)+SUM(numerics.HardAllocQty))/SUM(numerics.Value) AS AvgCost
    FROM dbo.tblPO_DETAIL_DATA PO 
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT   
          CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(po.cost) = 1 THEN CAST(po.cost as bigint) ELSE 0 END AS cost
    ) Numerics
    GROUP BY PO.[Part Number]
)

SELECT DISTINCT 
    part.Part_Num, part.[Part Description], part.[Part Type]
    , Stock.AvgPrice
    , PO.AvgCost as [Avg Cost]
FROM dbo.UNIQUE_PARTS_LIST part
LEFT OUTER JOIN StockByPart Stock ON stock.PartNo = part.Part_Num
LEFT OUTER JOIN POByPart PO ON PO.[Part Number] = part.Part_Num
```